# In the folder how do I make blender files show a preview of the model?

Tags: blend-files

In the folder where my models are saved, it used to display an image of that model in the icon but after updating my computer, it just displays the blender icon. Does anyone know how to change it so it shows a rendered preview of the model?

Here's a screenshot to show what I mean:
[image: butterfly model screenshot]

It used to display the model in the preview instead of the blender icon and I even tried rendering a view, saving it, closing blender and refreshing the folder but that didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm using windows 10 and my computer model is an MSI all in one touchscsreen gaming PC. Also I think my GPU is intel and it comes with Nvidia but I turned it off since it kept messing with blender but this was way before this file display issue happened, so I don't think it's the cause.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what OS you are using, how you installed blender, and your GPU.

Comment: @David Like that?

Comment: The reason I ask about the gpu is because the thumb nails are generated with an opengl render, if you do not have opengl support then no thumbnail is generated. Did you install blender with the installer, or just use it from the zip?

Comment: I had a zip file saved on my hard drive when I transferred the program over to my other computer. Should I try to redownload the same version from the website then? P:

Comment: Redownloading won't fix any problems. You might have to reinstall thought, so the thumbnail generator gets registered. You may need the installer version though, not the zipped setup.

Comment: Possible solution to your problem: https://blenderartists.org/t/blend-files-not-using-preview-thumbnails-in-windows-explorer/643180/7

Answer (score 4):

Usually, it's done via the windows installer file but sometimes it doesn't work.

You can do it manually though, using command lines.

First, you have to navigate to your Blender installation folder, which by default is `C:/Program files/Blender Foundation/Blender`.
A simple way to do it is to right-click a Blender shortcut and hit "open file location". You can find one of these shortcuts on your desktop, or in your start menu by typing in "Blender" in the search bar.
Or, if Blender is already running, right-click its icon in the taskbar → Properties → file location.

Once in Blender's folder, click on the path, write "cmd" and press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>. This will open a windows command prompt in the current folder.

Then type in the following command and press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>:

```
blender -R
```

If it goes correctly, it should answer this:

```
Registering file extension...success (user)
```

You just need to close any windows explorer windows and open again to apply the changes.
Alternatively, you can also do this via the following command:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe && start explorer.exe
```

Note that it will do the registration only for the current user. If you want to do it for the entire system:

- open the start menu
- type in "cmd"
- right-click the command line tools
- "run as administrator"
- run the command `chdir "C:/Program files/Blender Foundation/Blender"`(change your blender path if needed)
- run the command `blender -R`
- run the command `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe && start explorer.exe`
- voilà